# Suppose M is a finitely generated non-zero R-module, where R is a commutative unital ring. Show that the tensor product of M with itself is non-zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose M is a finitely generated non-zero R-module, where R is a commutative unital ring. Show that the tensor product of M with itself is non-zero.

I know one way to show this is to find an R-bilinear map which is nonzero, but am not sure how to find it.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this is the best proof, but here goes. Note that $M\otimes_R M = 0$ if and only if $(M\otimes_R M)_{\mathfrak p} = 0$ for all primes $\mathfrak p\subset R$ (Atiyah-MacDonald 3.8). But
$$
(M\otimes_R M)_{\mathfrak p}\cong M_\mathfrak p\otimes_{R_{\mathfrak p}}M_{\mathfrak p}
$$
by Atiyah-MacDonald 3.7.

Hence we have reduced to the case where $R$ is a local ring. The statement now follows from the fact that tensor product is faithful for finitely-generated modules over local rings, e.g. exercise 3 in the second chapter of Atiyah-MacDonald. (This is a consequence of Nakayama's lemma, as far as I remember.)

**Remark.** So why doesn't the argument given here show that tensor products are faithful over any ring via reduction to the local case? Simply because a pair of distinct modules $M$ and $N$ might be supported on disjoint sets of primes. For instance, this is the case when $R = \mathbb Z$, $M = \mathbb Z/p$ and $N = \mathbb Z/q$ for distinct primes $p,q$. Then $\mathbb Z /p\otimes\mathbb Z/q = 0$ because, with $r$ ranging over primes, $(\mathbb Z/p)_{(r)} = 0$ for $r\neq p$ and similarly for $q$.

Answer (score -2):

This is false. Let $R=\mathbb{C}[X]/(X^2)$. Let $x=\bar{X}$, so $x^2=0$, and let $M= R x$. Then $M$ is a finitely generated nonzero $R$-module, but $M\otimes M$ is generated by $x\otimes x=x^2\otimes 1=0\otimes 1=0$.

More generally, if $R$ is a commutative ring having a nonzero ideal $I$ satisfying $I^2=0$, then $I\otimes_R I=0$ and you get a counterexample.

Comment: No, $x^2 \otimes 1$ is not an element of $M\otimes M$.

Comment: There is a nonzero bilinear map $M \times M \to R$ given by $(ax, bx) \mapsto abx$, so $M \otimes_R M \neq 0$.

Comment: @o.h. I think $x^2\otimes 1=0$, how can this not be an element of $M\otimes M$?

Comment: @Jim where exactly is the mistake in GreginGre's answer? Is it that $x\otimes x$ is not a generator or is it that $x\otimes x\neq x^2\otimes 1$?

Comment: @Peter Melech The equation $x\otimes x = x^2\otimes 1$ does not make sense in $M\otimes M$  because $1\not\in M$. You are thinking of the rule $a\otimes rb = ra\otimes b$ for $a,b\in M$ and $r\in R$. But again, when GreginGre writes $x = x\cdot 1$, this is not of the form $rb$ for $b\in M$ since $1\not\in M$.

Comment: ($x\otimes x$ is a generator, that's not the problem.)

Comment: @o.h. Ah, I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Peter Melech No problem! I've made this mistake countless times myself :)